# function analytic in region symmetric about real axis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a simply connected domain symmetric about the real axis, and let $f$ be analytic in $D$.  The function $g$ defined by $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ should be analytic. However, I'm not getting that $g$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations since if  $f = u + iv$, we have $g = U + iV$ where $U(z) = u(\overline{z})$ and $V(z) = -{v(\overline{z})}$.  So

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\overline{z}) = \frac{\partial v }{\partial y} (\overline{z}) = -\frac{\partial  V}{\partial y}(z)$$

Where am I going wrong?  The minus sign shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

It might be clearer if we write $t = -y$, so $V(x,y) = -v(x,t)$.  Then using the Chain Rule,
$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y} = - \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} \dfrac{\partial t}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} =
\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x} $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you point out the flaw in my logic?

Comment: You didn't take the Chain Rule into account.